# How could I perform this replacement?

Tags: replacement

I essentially have something of the form

```
pm[1, 2] pm[3, 4] pm[5, 6] c[{1, 2, 5, 6}, "+"] c[{3, 4}, "-"]
```

I want to add next to each pm a corresponding plus or minus; so I want to have an expression that looks like

```
pm[1, 2]["+"] pm[3, 4]["-"] pm[5, 6]["+"] c[{1, 2, 5, 6}, "+"] c[{3, 4}, "-"]
```

Does anybody know a simple way to do this? My problem is that I'm not sure how to access the indices in the "c" and match them up with my list entries for each pm;

Edit: so here's a bit of an explanation of what is going on. I need to code the multiplication of two diagrams which looks like this:

[image: Diagram]

So the first cycle will have the representation in code of

```
pp[1,4]pp[2,3]pm[1,2]pm[3,4]c[{1,2,3,4},"+"]
```

while the second will look like

```
pp[1,2]pp[3,4]pm[1,2]pm[3,4]c[{1,2},"+"]c[{3,4},"-"]
```

So the "pp"s represent that matchings on *top* while the "pm"s represent the matchings on *bottom*. Each "c" tells me I have a cycle, as well as which vertices are in the cycle and if the cycle has been assigned a plus or minus.

So here's how the multiplication works; the bottom of the first and the top of the second get ignored, and I just get back the top of the first combined with the bottom of the second, with some replacement rules for the plus/minuses. Specifically,

$$(+,+)\to+$$
$$(+,-)\to -$$
$$(-,+)\to -$$
$$(-,-)\to 0$$

So the reason we get a minus out, is that between vertices 1 and 2 we get $(+,+)\to+$ and between 3 and 4 we get $(+,-)\to -$ and then overall we are left with $(+,-)\to-$ for the single cycle. So the way to get the "pp/pm" structure of the result is simple; I just ignore what I don't need. I need the "c" structures to tell me where my plus and minuses are. So what I'd ideally like my code to do is take our two inputs from the picture, and give me

```
pp[1,4]["+"]pp[2,3]["+"]pm[1,2]["+"]pm[3,4]["-"]
```

which I can then use to do some combining and give me a final result of

```
pp[1,4]pp[2,3]pm[1,2]pm[3,4]c[{1,2,3,4},"-"]
```

Yes I know this is long and convoluted. I'm also pretty new to Mathematica so if you think my whole approach is awful don't be afraid to tell me.

NOTE: I forgot to mention there may be an arbitrary (but always even) number of vertices. I just used four vertices in my example because it was simplest.

Comment: Quite a strange requirement.  Do you mind explaining why do you want to do this ? Perhaps there is a more standard way ...

Comment: ...Right: does it never happen that there exists a `pm[a, b]` where `a` is in `c[... "+"]` and `b` is in `c[... "-"]`? If that's *not* the case, I suspect that there's way to simplify your "data structure".

Comment: @march no, that'll never happen by the nature of this program.

Comment: @belisariusisforth I'll try to make an edit to explain, but it'll take a little bit of time

Comment: I posted an answer, but I recommend delaying accepting it until other answerers chime in with better answers and/or until you update your post with the explanation so that we can figure out the best way of going about doing things.

Comment: @belisariusisforth I've posted an edit.

Comment: My answer doesn't care about the arbitrary (but always even) number of vertices; it should still work. Questions: what is the important result at the end? Do you just care about the end result of a computation? Are you trying to generate all the elements in the algebraic structure? Etc. Out of general interest, what kind of algebraic structure results as a consequence of these objects and this multiplication?

Comment: It's part of an algorithm for Khovanov homology on tangles.

Comment: Yep; I don't have the background for that. Nonetheless, I'll think on a nice "data structure" for this problem. Perhaps it might be worth asking a separate question with the explanation of the problem as you've given it here, your current implementation of the "data structure" and the multiplication, what the output should be (end result of computation? all elements of the algebraic structure?) and a question seeking guidance as to how to better implement the problem in *Mathematica*. Would that fly, you think, @belisariusisforth?

Comment: @march http://katlas.org/wiki/Setup

Comment: @belisariusisforth. Heh heh, of course. There is even a page for Khovanov Homology.

Comment: Yes I'm very aware of the Knot Atlas. What I am trying to implement hasn't been implemented into a freely accessible program as far as I know

Comment: Please beware that Times is Orderless, so your expression could get reordered automagically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution, taking into account the fact that `p[a, b]` where `a` corresponds to `"+"` and `b` corresponds to `"="` (for instance) never happens:

```
rules = Flatten@Cases[expr, c[a_, b_] :> Thread[a -> b], Infinity]
expr /. pm[a_, b_] :> pm[a, b][a /. rules]
```

Comment: I went ahead and edited my post.